# How to force git to warn or add new files?

Tags: git, githooks, git-stage

We've all experienced that painful moment when a new feature works fine locally but breaks when deployed because we forgot to add a new file.

Is there a way to make git warn or automatically add new files when `git commit -a` is executed?

Comment: Always run a `git status` before committing, do you always commit blindly without checking what's in your index (to be committed stuff)? Besides, that's what `git commit -a` does... Commit every non-ignored file in your working tree.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, `git commit -a` does not consider untracked files -- to cite the part of the manual describing the `--all` option: "Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected. "

Comment: Yeah, my mistake there, still, doing a `git status` before `git commit` is the recommended. If you blindly `git add .` or something like that, you may be adding non-ignored junk to the project history. Which isn't easy to fix if it is pushed to the remote.

Answer (score 3):

A pre-commit hook like this should alarm about leftover files:

```
#!/bin/bash
. git-sh-setup # for 'die' cmd
git status --porcelain | while IFS= read -r line;
do
         if [[ $line == \?\?* ]] ; then # if the file begins with ?? it's untracked by git
                die "Uncommited files left!" # this will always terminate commit
                # say "Uncommited files left!" # this will just print the warning
         fi
done
```

Just [add this to your repo's pre-commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Installing-a-Hook) and voile :)

EDIT: you should also consider using some **continuous integration toolkit like Hudson or Buildbot** - it can perform a lot more comprehensive check then looking for missing files :)

EDIT2: unfortunately I didn't succeed in using read inside the loop so I think it might not be possible to make this hook ask for your action.

Answer (score 1):

```
git config --global alias.commita '!git add . && git commit -a'
```

After that just use:

```
git commita ..
```

instad of `git commit -a`. That will add new files too.